# JavaScriptSerializer to Serialize internal property member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Class Library project with something like this....

```
[DataContract]
public class DomainVerify
{
    [DataMember]
    internal string key { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public string mailbox { get; set; }
}
```

I made key Internal, so my other projects can't see this property. Now problem is, within the same project where I have "DomainVerify" Class, I am using JavaScriptSerialize to Serialize my Class into a JSON string & it seems like I can't serialze the "key" property since its "internal".

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(DomainVerify); // Skips Key property
```

is there anyway so I can hide this property to other projects and yet can serialize this property within same project?

Comment: I suggest you should try with DataContractJsonSerializer

Comment: I tried with the DataContract but to no avail. could you please check my update? Do I need to add something else as well to my code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use DataContractJsonSerializer.

Following is the example provided on MSDN. This example is with internal property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx.

I did not tried with JavaScriptSerializer but if there is some setting that allow then only it is possible to serialize internal so I suggest tried with DataContractJsonSerialier.

If this not solve your problem then look for Newton.Json.
http://www.tecsupra.com/serializing-only-some-properties-of-an-object-to-json-using-newtonsoft-json-net/

Last but not least make sure that your internal property has some value.

DataContractJsonSerializer

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DomainVerify verify = new DomainVerify() { domain = "test", key = "myKey", mailbox = "Newkey" };
            Console.WriteLine(GetJsonString(verify));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static string GetJsonString(object o)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(o.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ser.WriteObject(ms, o);
                string jsonData = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());                
                return jsonData;
            }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class DomainVerify
    {
        [DataMember]
        internal string key { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string domain { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string mailbox { get; set; }
    }
```

In case of WCF you have to mark each property that you want to take part in serialization using datacontract.

you have to add System.ServiceModel and System.Runtime.Serialization assembly.

In case of Json.net ( you have to add package)

```
public class DomainVerify
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]  // if you don't mark this attribute then as this is internal property it will not serilize.
        internal string key { get; set; }
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty] // as this is public property it always include in serilization unless you mark it with JsonIgnore.
        public string domain { get; set; }
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
        public string mailbox { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DomainVerify verify = new DomainVerify() { domain = "test", key = "myKey", mailbox = "Newkey" };
            Console.WriteLine(GetJsonString(verify));
            Console.ReadLine();            
        }

        public static string GetJsonString(object o)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
        }
     }
```

I hope above thing help you.

Note: I still have some doubt that if you pass this object from other project then it may possible that this field does not contain proper value or empty because it is internal.

Comment: Links and assumptions are not answers

Comment: I do agree with this and I will try to modify answer and at the time answer my only intention to help requester rather than to gain any point. If I put this thing in comment then it goes big.